# How to import package in online code editor?

Tags: python, import, package, editor

I'm trying to write in online editor with python2.7.  But I can't import library e.g `import igraph`.

How can I import it or every library to editors?
I can't find anything in their help.

Editors such as: [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php) or [repl](https://repl.it/languages/python)

Comment: sounds like its something to do with them not supporting the imports of those modules

Comment: Its not a standard library, so you cannot import like you normally do.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if neither the Tutorialspoint nor Repl.it interpreters have the igraph module installed on their end, and so you cannot import it. If you want to use igraph in an interpreter, you'll have to install it on your machine for use. Can be done with `pip install python-igraph`, and I'm sure there's a homebrew equivalent if you're on macOS.

Answer (score 0):

Currently Repl.it allows package installation: you need switch to the `Shell` tab and input  `pip install <package>` or whatever your want to be performed

Answer (score -1):

The online editor doesn't support installation of modules. You have to use something like PyCharm, Python IDE, or Anaconda to be able to install modules.

Comment: Choice of IDE has nothing to do with installing packages.